# watchdog stuck the flask web page

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, watchdog, python-watchdog

I am trying to create a document monitoring script with flask and watchdog

what I want to do is, if a file change in a directory it should immediately show in a web page. (if the web page is open in a browser)

initially, I tried printing the file change in the console while using below script,
when I routed to the localhost:5000/monitor in the browser, the browser is loading for a long time and if the file is changed it shows in the console out. I cannot understand why the browser is stuck can someone help me to understand this

```
@webapp.route('/monitor', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def monitor():

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    # path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    path = 'I:\\Projects\\files\\.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
    return 'monitor script running'
```

Comment: ```while True:
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Not a duplicate. These questions are unrelated

Answer (score 0):

Remove the infinite loop with `while True` and you are good.

```
@webapp.route('/monitor', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def monitor():

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    # path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    path = 'I:\\Projects\\files\\.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    return 'monitor script running'
```

Comment: this doesn't work